# d3 successive creation of nodes with selectAll().data().enter().append()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to create 2 times the number of nodes provided by an array in d3. The second time I try to create nodes with the same structure, the nodes are not created. I'm not familiar enough with d3 to understand why, and I'm hoping someone can help before I dig through the docs.

Example.

```
data = [1,2,3,4]

var someTag = d3.select("svg")
.append("div")
.attr("id","outer-div");

// this successfully creates the elements
someTag.select("div")
.data(data)
.enter().append("div")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d; }

// this does not create the elements
someTag.select("div")
.data(data)
.enter().append("div")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d*10; }
```

the goal is to have:

```
<div id="outer-div">
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
...
<div id="10"></div>
<div id="11"></div>
...
<div id="20"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select *different* elements (using `selectAll` instead of `select`):

```
someTag.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; });

someTag.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d*10; });
```

You can literally select elements, classes or IDs that don't exist, as I did here with `foo` and `bar`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4]

var someTag = d3.select("body")
.append("div");

someTag.selectAll("foo")
.data(data)
.enter().append("div")
.html(d=>d);

someTag.selectAll("bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("div")
.html(d=>d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**PS**: I'm only answering your question here, nothing more, but I have to say this: your code is not going to work. You **cannot** append a `<div>` to an SVG. Besides that, IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the code above is just a roughly written quick snippet. Crux of the issue was the selectAll on the same identifier.